# Hide the expand/collapse buttons in PhpStorm

Tags: ide, phpstorm

Is there a way to hide the expand/collapse buttons in PhpStorm?

I'm talking about these buttons:

[image]

I searched for it in the settings but I can't find it.

I'm trying to clean up the editor and I don't like these buttons in the gutter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `Settings/Preferences`
2. `Editor | General | Code Folding`
3. Uncheck the `Show code folding outline` option

[image]

Comment: Thanks it worked! Interesting thing is that I tried that option, hit apply and nothing happend. not until I hit ok it changed.

Comment: @TimBorowy Well .. it makes sense -- top window is still visible so no need to apply/re-draw such big change (window composition changes) straight away.